# Capturing focus on a specific jQueryUI tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQueryUI tabs, and on a specific tab, I have defined a click function (the ajax call works correctly):

```
$("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").click(function (event, ui)
{

     //ajax call

});
```

Now what I am trying to do is to accomodate not just clicks, but any type of focus on this tab in general, such as navigating to it using a keyboard arrow key for example. I tried `activate` in place of `click`, but I got an error. How can I capture all types of focus on a specific jQueryUI tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working as follows:

I initialized tabs in my application using the class attribute instead of an id, and within it is specified the `activate` option. In there, I got the id of the currently active tab using `$(".tabui .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");` where `tabui` is the name of the class. The code is below.

```
$('.tabui').tabs({

    activate: function (event, ui)
    {

       //do something 1

        var currentTab = $(".tabui .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");

        console.log (currentTab);

        if(currentTab ===  "#tabs-1ua")
        {
             //do something 2
        }


    }
});
```

Thanks to all who replied trying to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should set "tabsactivate" listener while the tab has been activated. Please check below code.

//tabs is the id of UL in which all the tabs has been wrapped. Please replace it with according to your code.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event ,ui){  
        if(ui.newTab.attr('href')=='#tabs-1ua'){
            //make ajax call
        }
});
```

Comment: This did not work for keyboard navigation focus or mouse click focus.

Comment: @ITWorker you are working with which version of jquery ui?

Comment: the updated answer did not work either. I am using version 1.11.4

Comment: @ITWorker What is the id of "UL" in which all the tabs(li) has been wrapped?

Comment: there is no id for the UL. I initialized the tabs using the class attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118946/discussion-between-rahul-patel-and-itworker).

Comment: @ITWorker Ok that's great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").on('click hover', function () {
// Do something for both
});
```

Comment: I just tried it, and there was no difference in behavior with `click`

Comment: @ITWorker I added new way.Check if that works for you

Comment: @IIP TT nothing happens on hover.

Answer (score 0):

`focus()` by default is accepted by input elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`) and not `<a>` elements. Try adding a tab index to the anchor first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").attr("tabindex", "-1").focus(function 
    (event, ui) {
        // JS goes here
    });

});
```

Comment: This has the same behavior as the click, it didn't capture navigating to the tab with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use the `focus` event for key movement, and can use it for mouse clicks as well.  The `focus` event and related events are notoriously quirky in their behaviors, especially with respect to how they are implemented in frameworks and plugins.  While I can't say just why, `focus` on the `a` element fires on a mouse click, and `focus` on the enclosing `li` element fires when you navigate to the element with keys.  (Tested with Chrome.)  So:

```
$("#myTabs").tabs();
$('#myTabs li, #myTabs a').on('focus', function(e, ui){
    //do whatever
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/robtrodes/rua3v2sb/31/)

Comment: How can I do this only for one specific tab? The one referred to by `"a[href='#tabs-1ua']"`

Comment: You could just give the containing `li` element an id and reference the id.  Sounds like you might need to have a closer look at [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors), or understand more clearly that jQuery uses CSS selectors to determine what to do things to.  The selector in my example refers to "any `li` element inside the element with the id 'myTabs', OR any `a` element inside the id 'myTabs'.  If you can't figure it out from there, post back.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks for the help.